# MacPorts: violation of the ports-filesystem hierarchy in the destroot phase

Tags: makefile, installation, macports

I'm in the process of developing a Portfile for my application and I'm running into problems during the destroot phase. According to the [MacPorts guide](http://guide.macports.org/#reference.phases), the destroot phase executes the following command:

```
make install DESTDIR=${destroot}
```

I think I may be misunderstanding how this is supposed to work in the Makefile. My application is very simple and the install rule only needs to copy a few directories to the `DESTDIR` so it is specified as follows:

```
install:
    cp -R bin $(DESTDIR)/bin
    cp -R lib $(DESTDIR)/lib
    cp -R cfg $(DESTDIR)/cfg
```

However, when I try to do a MacPort installation of my application, I get the following warnings:

```
--->  Staging test into destroot
Warning: violation by /bin
Warning: violation by /lib
Warning: violation by /cfg
Warning: test violates the layout of the ports-filesystems!
```

How do I fix this? Am I misunderstanding how the `DESTDIR` variable is used in the install rule or missing something altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directories need to be put under **DESTDIR** as if you are starting at `/.`,  For example, instead of using `$(DESTDIR)/bin` you should be using `$(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/bin` - where `$(PREFIX)` is `/opt/local` or whatever.